# Sticky close button for foundation 6 reveal

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-reveal

Problem:  when Reveal data is taller than window height, scrolling moves the close icon off the page.  I want to make it sticky so that you always have the option of closing the page without scrolling back up to the top.

I have tried loading the foundation 6 `.sticky` example into the reveal, but none of my attempts have been successful.

This is what I think should work, which is loaded into the reveal container `<div id="modal2" style="height: 100%"></div>` via ajax. Unfortunately, the close button just scrolls with the content.

```
<script>
    // this script cannot be located in the layouts.js, 
    // because the trigger doesn't exist at page load.

    $('#close-modal2').click(function(){
        // $('#modal2').foundation('close'); didn't work for some reason.  
        // 'open' closes all other modals, so it accomplishes what I need.
        $('#modal').foundation('open');
    });

</script>



<div>
    <button id="close-modal2" class="close-button sticky" 
            aria-label="Close reveal" type="button" data-sticky>
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>

<div id="paragraph-wrapper" data-sticky-container>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-11 small-centered columns">
            <div> Lots of content here, enough to overflow window...</div>
            <div> Losts of content here..... etc.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I missing something?  Has anyone else been able to get a sticky close button in a reveal?

Answer (score 0):

The basic behaviour of the Reveal is to close if the user clicks outside of the reveal container, so a user does already have a quick way of exiting the reveal.

However, you could also use `position: fixed;` on the close element.

That would keep it in the same spot while the modal scrolled up and down.

**CSS**

```
#modal2 > .close-button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1rem; //or whatever
    right: 2rem; //or whatever
}
```

[e.g. in a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/Lekq0y48/2/)

Using `position: fixed;` is a bit of a pain for styling and mobiles but that will be depending on your particular design.